# Skipping getline()

Tags: c++, cin, getline

- 

> I've encountered a problem with getline(). I've googled it and checked
> multiple pages, but those answers aren't meant for newbies like me.
> Here's the code: `#include <iostream> #include <string.h> using namespace std; int main(){  string n,s,a,ad,e;  cout<<"Your name: "<<endl;  cin>>n;     cout<<"Hello, "<<n<<endl;   cout<<"Your surname: "<<endl;   cin>>s;     cout<<"Your age: "<<endl;  cin>>a;     cout<<"Your address: "<<endl;   getline(cin,ad); cout<<"Your email: "<<endl;     cin>>e;     cout<<"Done."<<endl; cout<<"Name: "<<n<<" "<<s<<endl;    cout<<"Age: "<<a<<endl; cout<<"Address: "<<ad<<endl;    cout<<"Email: "<<e<<endl; }`  The
> problem is that the getline(cin,ad) just skips whenever I launch the
> program. It goes this way: `Your name: name Hello, name Your surname: surname Your age: age Your address: Your email:`  As you
> can see, I can't enter my address, because the getline() gets skipped.
> How can I fix this, simply?

I solved the problem, I just should've written:

```
cin>>ad;
getline(cin, ad);
```

and that's all. Thanks for your contribution!

Comment: You are mixing `getline` and stream extraction using `operator>>`.  After the `cin>>a` you probably want to do `cin.ignore(ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` to clear out the rest of the line for the age input.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix getline and >>.

The user will ***always*** press Enter after every input you ask for.

In general, use getline to get user input. If you need further processing afterwards, use a stringstream or one of the standard string-to-integer or string-to-float functions.

In your case, everything you ask for is a string, so there isn't any point in using anything but getline anyway.

(Especially when it comes to names.)